# How to create App.Manifest file in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, vb.net, com

**Target:
I need to access the .NET 4.0 Framework Dll methods from VB.NET 2.0 Framework Windows application.**

To achieve this in C# windows application, 
I have downloaded the sample code from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx)

Everything works fine in C# windows app. i.e) i can access .NET 4.0 dll methods from 2.0 Framework C# windows application.

Now, I need to access the  .NET 4.0 Framework  Dll from the VB.NET 2.0 Application.

In sample code they using App.manifest file to registering the COM objects and setting the dependencies.

But I dont know/ struggling in creating/adding **app.manifest file in VB.NET application? and implementing the same using VB.NET app**

Your answers highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: The sample you posted is c++.  An easier approach would be to set the c# application project properties to Framework 2.0.  You will be restricted in the methods you can use.  Once you have a 2.0 c# application it should be easy to add to your VB.NET 2.0 application.

Comment: Forcing .NET 4 to be used cannot be done with a manifest, it requires a config file with the supportedRuntime element instead.  Since such a config file forces .NET 4 to be used, there is no point in still targeting 2.0.  Testing a ComVisible assembly with a .NET program is quite pointless, just add a reference to the assembly instead.

Comment: Finally worked well. Now i can call the .NET 4 Dll method app from 2.0 VB.NET application. Thanks all.